# When is the derivative of a function equal to the integral of the same function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

My question basically is :

> $$\text{When is}\space  \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) = \int f(x)$$

Is there any condition for these two to be equal?

My attempt was to take the derivative of both the sides, getting:
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x) = f(x)$$ which is equivalent to solving the differential equation:
$$\begin{align} f''(x) = f(x) \Rightarrow f''(x) - f(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = C_1 e^x + C_2 e^{-x}
\end{align}$$
Is my approach correct? Is there any other approach which leads to the same answer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your approach is correct, and there are theorems in the solving of ODEs which show that the solution you have obtained is complete.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks for your confirmation :)

Comment: Pedantic note: your calculation shows that any solution must be a function of that form—but one must still check that every function of that form is indeed a solution. (Note that the first step, taking derivatives, can in principle make distinct functions equal; so checking is necessary, if you're not using a theorem that has already done that work.)

Comment: @GregMartin Perhaps; differentiating those two functions twice can easily be done mentally, and you can see almost by inspection that they satisfy the DE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach and result are all correct. You can check the same by back substitution. Btw, if

$$  \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) = -\int f(x) dx $$

then by a similar token

$$ f(x) = C_3 \cos x  + C_4 \sin x .$$